# Testdriven.Net And NUnit Exception

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, testdriven.net

Recently something happened to my TD.Net environment. When running tests with TD.Net, its looking for nunit 2.4.6.  This happens with any project that uses NUnit as my testing framework. No references to that version in any of my projects. Have un-installed / re-installed both the latest NUnit and TD.Net several times. TD.Net works fine with projects that use xunit. Any tips? Here is the exception:

```
failed: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'nunit.framework, Version=2.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, RuntimeTypeHandle* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount)
at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandle(Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
at System.Reflection.Module.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, Module decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(Module decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes)
at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
at NUnit.Core.Reflect.GetAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider member, Boolean inherit)
at NUnit.Core.Reflect.HasAttribute(ICustomAttributeProvider member, String attrName, Boolean inherit)
at NUnit.Core.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.CanBuildFrom(Type type)
at NUnit.Core.Extensibility.SuiteBuilderCollection.CanBuildFrom(Type type)
at NUnit.Core.TestFixtureBuilder.CanBuildFrom(Type type)
at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.GetFixtures(Assembly assembly, String ns)
at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
at NUnit.AddInRunner.NUnitTestRunner.run(ITestListener testListener, Assembly assembly, ITestFilter filter)
at NUnit.AddInRunner.NUnitTestRunner.runMethod(ITestListener testListener, Assembly assembly, MethodInfo method)
at NUnit.AddInRunner.NUnitTestRunner.RunMember(ITestListener testListener, Assembly assembly, MemberInfo member)
at TestDriven.TestRunner.AdaptorTestRunner.Run(ITestListener testListener, ITraceListener traceListener, String assemblyPath, String testPath)
at TestDriven.TestRunner.ThreadTestRunner.Runner.Run()
```

Comment: I had a third party library unrelated to my td.net and my project that had a dependency on 2.4.6, updating that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you move the location of your unit tests or the location of nunit?

Comment: No, it's worked fine forever, nothing has moved.  Can't figure out what I did to break it. And why its looking for 2.4.6 instead of 2.5.  The Test Runners option window says 2.5.

Comment: Did you try installing 2.4.6?